# Update Cell on VBA

Tags: vba, excel, copy

I want to Update B1 cell . I already made this:

```
Sub test()
x = 1
y = 1

    Do While Cells(y, 1).Value <> "" 
      If Cells(y, 1) > 0 Then    Cells(y, 2).Value = Cells(x, 3).Value
         x = x + 1
         y = y + 1
      End If
 Loop
End Sub
```

The A1 cell is empty so I would like use this form when I type in a number for A1.
After typed in the number for A1 the c1 cell is going to get me another number 
 with Vlookup function.

This C1 number what I want to convert for only number(without function) so that's why I want to copy C1 value for B1
Only need me to update the B1 after I typed in The A1 and the C1 comes up.

At the moment I only can use as macro when I type in the A1 and C1 comes up after I start to use macro. What I want when I type in for A1 and C1 comes up than the B1 is goint to show the C1 value automaticaly .
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [Worksheet_Change event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/worksheet-change-event-excel).

To start, you'll need to double-click the appropriate sheet in the Visual Basic Editor:

[image]

That will open that sheet's code module.  Then copy/paste this code into it:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rCheck As Range
    Dim ChangedCell As Range

    Set rCheck = Intersect(Target, Me.Columns("A"))

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not rCheck Is Nothing Then
        For Each ChangedCell In rCheck.Cells
            If ChangedCell.Value > 0 Then Me.Cells(ChangedCell.Row, "B").Value = Me.Cells(ChangedCell.Row, "C").Value
        Next ChangedCell
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Note that you could use the .Offset property to set the value (e.g. `ChangedCell.Offset(, 1).Value = ChangedCell.Offset(, 2).Value`), I just prefer being explicit instead of using Offset which can be difficult to read and debug.

Comment: Thank you ! Now it's working so I can carry on to work on the workbook. Thanks again